# Can only use PyDev plugin when running Eclipse as root or using -clean option

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, pydev

#### Overview

I am running Ubuntu 15.10 with Eclipse Mars 4.5.2 (from the Oomph installer) and and Java 1.8 and Python 2.7. I am attempting to the PyDev 5.2.0 plugin for Eclipse. Installing with Eclipse's update manager seemed to go okay. The only problem is that I can only see PyDev related options when I run Eclipse with sudo.

#### What I have tried

- I made sure to set the java VM path in the eclipse.ini file so the Eclipse binary runs with Java 8.
- I added Java 8 to Eclipse's JREs and set to be default.
- I tried running the Eclipse binary with the `-clean` option.

The first two didn't allow me access to the PyDev options in Eclipse. Running as a normal user with the `-clean` option did let me see the PyDev options, but running as a normal user without `-clean` made the PyDev menu options invisible again.

Finally, I noticed that running Eclipse as root made the PyDev options appear again. This suggested that there was some ownership or permission problem. Since my Eclipse installation and plugins are in my home directory, I made sure my user has ownership over everything in the home directory. I also reviewed the permissions of files related to the PyDev plugin, and it appears I have the appropriate permissions, but since I do not know which permissions each file ought to have, I am not sure.

---

I am  not sure what is going on. It is especially surprising given that I was able to install the CDT plugin not long ago without any hassle. It's also possible the problem might be related to how root's environment is configured compared to my user's, but being able to access PyDev when running with `-clean` seems to vanquish that theory.

I could just run Eclipse as root from now on, which isn't that big of a deal. However, it is quite annoying not knowing why this is happening, making me feel like I don't have control over Ubuntu and Eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04 solved my problem. After the upgrade, PyDev was working normally in Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you have the eclipse **configuration** folder not accessible by the current user (or some other folder inside the **.metadata**).

Try verifying/fixing the permissions on those folders (I don't exactly know where those folders go on the default ubuntu install, but on windows it's **eclipse/configuration** and the **.metadata** is where you point your workspace to).

Comment: Thanks for your help Fabio, I really like PyDev! I checked the permissions and ownership of both **configuration** and **.metadata** and unfortunately found that they were already set appropriately. I set them again to make sure, but no luck. Interestingly, I tried upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04 and that solved my problem. I am not sure what changed to make PyDev work though. Perhaps it is specific to Ubuntu 15.10

Comment: Well, not sure, Linux distributions can change a lot the structure of Eclipse deployment (personally, I use LiClipse, which has all bundled, so, I don't usually have much issues on that front). Anyways, great that it works now ;)